# Is there a way I can set generated paths for Angular cli Json?

Tags: angular-cli

Lets say I want to set a path for

```
ng generate service my-service
```

to always go in my **services** folder in my src/app/services of the project. Is there a way to configure the json / ng-set=path for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like that in cli.

However you can generate a service in the right folder just by specifying the path:  `ng generate service /services/my-service`

Also you can `cd` in to the destination folder and by running `ng generate service my-service` it should create the service in a current folder.